# How to stack data by removing duplicates in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```html
df1<-read.table(text=" Id Cost Type T1_MOT1_2 T2_NOT3_4
   M 100 MOT2 N N
12 120 MOT3 N N
23 100 MOT2 N N
11 111 MOT1 Y N
N 33 MOT4 N N
14 44 MOT2 N N
Q 77 MOT3 N N
P 96 MOT3 N N
Z 90 MOT1 Y N
P 34 MOT3 N N
H 19 MOT4 N Y
B 23 MOT2 Y N

    ",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table

```html
Id Cost Type T1_MOT1_2 T2_NOT3-4
M 100 MOT2 N N
23 100 MOT2 N N
11 111 MOT1 Y N
14 44 MOT2 N N
Z 90 MOT1 Y N
B 23 MOT2 Y N
H 19 MOT4 N Y
```

The first step, I want to get data related to MOT1 and MOT2 (codes are M, 23, 11 and 14). The second step, I want to add data based on T1_MOT1_2 and T2_NOT3-4. If I see “Y” in both (for T1_MOT1_2  I will get codes 12 and Q and for T2_NOT3-4 I will get N. 
Important Point, if the data has been already selected in the first steps, I do NOT want to repeat them in the outcome.

I can get the first step using this:

```
subset(df1, Type == 'MOT1'| Type== 'MOT2')
```

However, I failed to get the intended outcome. Can we do it?

Comment: Only a single row is removed here

Comment: Do you need `subset(df1, Type == 'MOT1'| Type== 'MOT2'|T1_MOT1_2 == "Y"|T2_NOT3_4 == 'Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the expected, it seems that we want to subset either 'Type' as 'MOT1', 'MOT2' or the rest of the 'Type' based on different condition

```
subset(df1, (Type == 'MOT1'| Type== 'MOT2')|
       (!(Type %in% c('MOT1', 'MOT2'))) & (T2_NOT3_4 == 'Y'|T1_MOT1_2  == 'Y'))
#    Id Cost Type T1_MOT1_2 T2_NOT3_4
#1   M  100 MOT2         N         N
#3  23  100 MOT2         N         N
#4  11  111 MOT1         Y         N
#6  14   44 MOT2         N         N
#9   Z   90 MOT1         Y         N
#11  H   19 MOT4         N         Y
#12  B   23 MOT2         Y         N
```

Comment: @User20100  One of the issues with the example is that you can get the expected output through different ways and this may not obey your conditions

Comment: @User20100  My point is that all of them are giving the expected output.  If you can update your example where this gives a different result, it may be useful

Comment: @User20100  If I do `subset(df1, (Type == 'MOT1'| Type== 'MOT2')|(!(Type %in% c('MOT1', 'MOT2'))) & T2_NOT3_4 == 'Y')` I get the expected

Comment: @User20100  Try   the  `subset(df1, (Type == 'MOT1'| Type== 'MOT2')|
       (!(Type %in% c('MOT1', 'MOT2'))) & (T2_NOT3_4 == 'Y'|T1_MOT1_2  == 'Y'))`